# Writing Python2.7 unittest with Mock (URLError: <urlopen error unknown url type: http>)

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking

Been struggling with making some test cases for my code for days now.
I wrote a code to batch download files with a given input in a form of a string of URL or a list of strings of URLs.  My code currently supports 4 protocols (http, https, ftp, sftp)

I've been reading stuff about Mock and watched some videos. I still can't apply the samples I've seen on the internet to my actual code. :(

Below are my implementation for batch download and the unit test I wrote that is still failing:

```
def batch_download(url):
 req = Request(url)
try:
    print '\nStart downloading...'
    response = urlopen(req)
except URLError as e:
    # No network connection or Invalid URL or The specified server doesn't exist.
    if hasattr(e, 'reason'):
        print 'We failed to reach a server.'
        print 'Reason: ', e.reason
    # HTTP Response that is not 200.
    elif hasattr(e, 'code'):
        print 'The server couldn\'t fulfill the request.'
        print 'Error code: ', e.code
else:
    # Retrieve a redirected URL, if there is one.
    real_url = response.geturl()
    print real_url
    saved_to = get_local_path(real_url)
    urlretrieve(real_url, saved_to)

    # meta_data = response.info()['Content-Length']
    # file_on_disk = os.stat(saved_to).st_size
    # print '\nContent-Length: ' + meta_data
    # print 'File on Disk after Download: ' + str(file_on_disk)
    remove_partially_downloaded(real_url, response, saved_to)

    urlcleanup()
return



def remove_partially_downloaded(url, response, local_path_to_file):
 meta_data = response.info()['Content-Length']
 file_on_disk = os.stat(local_path_to_file).st_size
 print '\nContent-Length: ' + meta_data
 print 'File on Disk after Download: ' + str(file_on_disk)

 partial_download = int(meta_data) - file_on_disk

 if partial_download > 0:
    print '\nThe following partially downloaded file ' + get_filename_from_url(url) + ' will be removed'
    os.remove(local_path_to_file)
 else:
    return
```

Had a problem formatting the unittest code. So I attached an image of my unittest class here instead
[image]

And the failure message I got is the following 
[image]

Any help is appreciated. Suggestion for using patch and MagicMock is highly appreciated. I know the basic concepts of those two but still can't figure out where to incorporate those into my code. I'm very new at this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I think there are two blockers at play. First, you are executing more than just your code. Dependencies, such as urllib2 are not being isolated correctly. In fact, the Error is raised in that library's code. Second, it is not clear what you are trying to test. To fix this, I propose to use the [AAA pattern](https://www.typemock.com/unit-test-patterns-for-net#aaa) to write your tests.

Let's start with the second issue. You want to have 3 sections for your test:

- Arrange. In this first section you set up everything you will need to execute your code. This includes creating mocks and instructing them to respond however you would like.
- Act. Now you call your the unit of code you wish to test, in this case batch_download.
- Assert. Verify that output from your code equals your expected result, or verify that your mock was called as expected. Ideally you should include only one assert in this section, therefore testing only one thing with each test.

In your test, you are calling batch_download before setting up the mocks. Then, you set some mocks (albeit incorrectly, see below), and then call another function of your code. There is no assert.

Maybe it is difficult to come up with a simple, AAA, one-assert test for your method. That's because your function is doing many things. Try to refactor into several functions, each doing a single, directly testable thing. (I highly recommend you check out Robert Martin's book "Clean Code", it provides several tips and guidelines to improve the quality of your code.)

As for the mocks. You shouldn't use urllib2 openers for this. First and foremost, because then your would be testing that library along with your code. The test becomes a sort of integration test, and one that is not very good either because it introduces new logic not found in the original method (extra failing point). Second, its much easier to just use mock library for that.

An easy way to mock that dependency would be using patch. As an example, let's test that if urlopen does not raise an Error (returns a response), and geturl is called on the response, then urlretrive will be called with the expected url and save_to path:

```
import mock
...
@mock.patch('test_obj.urllib2')
def test_batch_download(self, urllib2_mock):
    # Arrange:
    response_mock = mock.MagicMock()
    real_url = 'http://sample.com'
    response_mock.geturl.return_value = real_url
    urllib2_mock.urlopen.return_value = response_mock

    # Act:
    test_obj.batch_download('http://originalurl.com')

    # Assert:
    expected_save_to_path = '/var/dl/sample.com'
    urllib2_mock.urlretrive.assert_called_once_with(real_url, expected_save_to_path)
```

I hope this helps. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks a lot Guido! I was struggling with mocking a Request and Response object in particular when I started writing a test for this function. Used urlopener inside my test because I found another post on stack overflow suggesting that's the approach for mocking the response. Anyways thanks again! :)